# Creating a view that groups results by month/year

Tags: 7, views

Does anyone know how to build a view that groups the results by Month/Year but can print the results expanded. Take the following dataset:

**Events**

```
    Event Name  Event Date
    ----------  ----------
    Event 1     2011-05-01
    Event 2     2011-05-15
    Event 3     2011-05-30
    Event 4     2011-06-04
    Event 5     2011-06-22
    Event 6     2011-07-01
    Event 7     2011-08-16
    Event 8     2012-01-01
    Event 9     2012-01-02
    Event 10    2013-05-15
```

I would like Views to output that data in the following format:

```
    May 2011
    --------
      Event 1
      Event 2
      Event 3

    June 2011
    ---------
      Event 4
      Event 5

    July 2011
    ---------
      Event 6

    August 2011
    -----------
      Event 7

    January 2012
    ------------
      Event 8
      Event 9

    May 2013
    --------
      Event 10
```

So the view would not actually be grouped in SQL it just needs to print out the events with headings visually grouped by month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it would be possible to group by month like that, but it would be pretty simple to do this in a template (or a preprocess function).

All you really need to do is to loop through all the rows and check if the event has a new month/year. Each time that happens you add the event date formatted as `Month year`. This would also give you the flexibility to print the months like fx `h3` or whatever fits your site best, instead of relying on the markup views would generate.

Comment: I've actually already done this in code using EntityQuery and grouping manually. Seems like a real limitation of Views that it can't do this.

Comment: @camsoft Views could have added this, but with the number of different ways it would have to be implemented across SQL servers like MySQL, PgSQL etc, I can see why this isn't added. People do like you do, create the query themselves instead of adding this feature in views.

Comment: @googletorp I am new in drupal, can you please answer this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/120546/28667

Answer (score 15):

You can group by any field, including Month-year. You have to select your date field and customize the output. Then, Views can group on the field, using the "Grouping" options under Format: Settings.

Comment: To make the video even more fantastic and useful, it could go into the user's next problem: "confusing sorting under each month heading". To add the confusing thing: Add another Post Date field, to be displayed next to the Title, with the custom date format Y-m-d. The blog posts are  now presented in a jumbled order.

Comment: I didn't watch your video, but if it is not included, you will have to enable "Remove tags from rendered output" to get the grouping to work properly. This has something to do with RDF in core (if enabled). It can mess with grouping if this isn't enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using Views and have it displayed as a table. Table has an option to group fields.

Comment: If grouping by date, sometime we may need to uncheck 'Use rendered output to group rows' option for grouping to work.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7, with Views 3, KarenS recommends disabling the RDF module in Core.  That's all that has worked for me.  http://drupal.org/node/1253562#comment-4886998