# How to add dynamic fields with condition?

Tags: nodes

I have a website that is about automobiles, I want when a user choose a brand drupal shows some of its models:

This image show an example:

for example I want when a user selected **BMW** drupal shows BMW's models in other **select tag** dynamic. and for example selected **Lamborghini**  drupal shows Lamborghini's models.

[image: select a car model]

**I mean a tree stystem**

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use any one of following modules.

[Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.

[Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs)

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies hierarchy.

[Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree)

> This module provides an expandable tree widget for the Taxonomy Term Reference field in Drupal 7. This widget is intended to serve as a replacement for Drupal's core Taxonomy Term Reference widget, which is a flat list of radio buttons or checkboxes and not necessarily fit for medium to large taxonomy trees.

Comment: what are these?

Comment: These are contributed modules that gives you feature of such type of problem, you are facing. Gone through once from any of links, get brief idea of each. Your problem looks like the same that these modules can easily solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [conditionnal fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module which is based on the [States API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7) if you want to do this hardcoded.

An other way to do this is by using hierarchical taxonomy and a module like [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) even though you might be limited.

Comment: I want editors do it now super user or administrator

Comment: Once the module or your taxonomy is configured then the editors will be able to do this.

Comment: I should test it